# Графики в java

Tags: java

С помощью какой библиотеки можно отрисовывать графики?
Нужно, чтобы была возможность обозначать координатные оси и рисовать 2 графика одновременно

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Графики Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/251247/%d0%93%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8-java)

Answer (score 3):

было на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265777/what-is-the-best-open-source-java-charting-library-other-than-jfreechart).

[http://trac.erichseifert.de/gral/](http://trac.erichseifert.de/gral/wiki/Gallery) точно умеет.