# Графики Java

Tags: java, диаграммы

Пишу маленькое приложение для самообучения, есть сервер и клиент, в базе данных сервера есть таблица с полями (id, дата, доллар, евро), каким способом лучше передать эти данные клиенту и какой библиотекой построить графики?

Answer (score 1):

javafx предоставляет удобные средства для построения графиков, а т.к. она входит в jdk начиная с какого-то апдейта семерки, и у вас стоит версия с fx, то имхо делать надо на ней

Answer (score 0):

А мне вот эта либа нравится: http://xeiam.com/xchart.jsp 
Просто и со вкусом.